# SQL Server Management Studio error when trying to edit table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I got the following message when I try to edit a table through SQL Server Management Studio.

The machine is my company remote desktop. and everyone in the company tried to do the same failed too. Any ideas? I tried to search around, the people telling me to edit the DbProviderFactory files under C:. but I don't want to.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (SQLEditors)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The 'DbProviderFactories' section can only appear once per config file. (System.Configuration)

Answer (score 8):

Remove empty element DbProviderFactories in machine config files:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Machine.Config
```

Comment: This worked for me.  There may also be a Framework64 subdirectory (everything else being the same).  Be sure to update the two Machine.Config files there, as well.

Comment: Just to add a bit more.... note that when you install IBM DB2 Providers ()IBMDA400, IBMDARLA, IBMDASQL, etc) for use with Linked Servers, this fix will always be required.  This problem will also show up when you try to create/use Database Diagrams but gives you a slightly different error (I don't have the exact error any more but it won't say anything about DbProviderFactories).  You won't need to reboot the box but you will need to restart SSMS.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. My issue arose when I installed a MySQL data connector, which I then uninstalled. Although uninstalled, the references were still in the Machine.Config. Once located and removed from the DbProviderFactories  section . I restarted MSSMS and Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, but i had the same issue and resolved it by using different approach.

First of all, i would like to thank for [Mihai Bejenariu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881345/mihai-bejenariu). His solution pointed me out in the right direction even if i haven't found empty entry for **DbProviderFactories**.

Some time ago i had to install Firebird database with .net drivers for it. When i finished a project, i decided to remove a Firebird database and drivers, BUT... some entries haden't removed from **machine.config** files under **Framework64** directory (as i'm using Win10 64bit). See:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
    <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
    <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
    <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

When i removed them, i was able to create/open database diagram.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not sophisticated, just tragicomic

I was editing my tables using design in MS SQL. I started to get the same error.  Then I remembered that I had set up **my SQL connection**. After I deleted it, the problem was solved.

The END